# Function to move around keys in serde_yaml Value type in Rust

Tags: rust, yaml

I have a yaml file that looks like this:

```
columns:
    - name: col1
      type: date
      description: a date field
      semantics:
        type: dimension
    - name: col2
      type: integer
      description: some int field

semantics:
  identifiers:
    - name: device
  dimensions:
```

I'd like to move any semantics references under the `columns` to the `dimensions` key in the bottom block like so:

```
columns:
    - name: col1
      type: date
      description: a date field
    - name: col2
      type: integer
      description: some int field

semantics:
  identifiers:
    - name: device
  dimensions:
    - col1
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
pub fn swap_semantics(m: &Mapping) {
    if let Some(col) = m.get("columns") {
        let out: Vec<_> = col
            .as_sequence()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .map(|c| {
                if let Some(val) = c.as_mapping() {
                    if val.contains_key("semantics") {
                        val.get("name").take()
                    } else {
                        None
                    }
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
            .filter(|c| c.is_some())
            .flatten()
            .map(|f| f.as_str().unwrap())
            .collect();
        //.for_each(|f| println!("{:?}", f));

        let mut dims = HashMap::new();
        dims.insert("dimensions", out);
        println!("{:?}", dims);
    }
}
```

It works, but it's ugly and seemingly excessively verbose.

Is there a better way to work with Value types? There are other keys that can exist on these yaml keys which could be list types or other, which make it difficult to simply deserialize into a HashMap. The other option is to define several structs with lots of optional fields, which also seems like high friction.

Comment: The "other option" with several structs is actually the way to go if you know in advance the layout of your data, and it's actually quite straightforward. It's almost like writing in Rust how you expect your data to be, add a `#[derive(Deserialize)]` tag and *voilà*!

Comment: I do know it, for the most part. The presence of the fields is highly variant so it felt like extra steps to still handle a medley of `Option<T>` types, but it's probably still the better way to go. Thank you!